# Function na.approx refuses character

Tags: r, interpolation

I would just like to interpolate by using the "constant" method but character seems not to be supported by approx function what could I do.

```
  library(zoo)     
  na.approx(c('a', NA, NA,'b', NA, NA,'a', NA, NA, NA, NA), 
            maxgap = 3,
            method = "constant")
  # should return : c('a', 'a', 'a','b', 'b', 'b','a', NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

Instead it gives the error message:

> Error in approx(x[!na], y[!na], xout, ...) : zero non-NA points

Comment: Well you set `maxgap` to 3, so the last four values remained `NA` as they were.  What values do you want to have there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

You should use `na.locf`:

```
na.locf(x, maxgap = 3, na.rm = FALSE)
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a" NA  NA  NA  NA
```

---

### Original answer

`na.approx` only accept numeric vectors. But you can do this manually:

```
na.approx.char.con <- function(x, maxgap){
    ave(x, cumsum(!is.na(x)), FUN = function(x){
        if(length(x) > maxgap + 1){
            x
        }else{
            rep(x[1], length(x))
        }
    })
}

x <- c('a', NA, NA,'b', NA, NA,'a', NA, NA, NA, NA)
na.approx.char.con(x, maxgap = 3)
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "a" NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to map characters to integers (as `factor` variables) and then use `na.approx`.

Comment: @Roland, I finally found `na.locf` is the right function for this job!